# Angular JS $state conditional from controller is not working

Tags: angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing, angularjs-ng-click

I have a wizard in AJS and it has around 10 views. Based on user selection and other parameter my controller decide next view and set $state.go('new view'). But the code seems to be not working.. not sure the issue though.

Here is my Routing..

```
$stateProvider

    // route to show our basic form (/form)
    .state('form', {
        url: '/form',
        templateUrl: 'form.html',
        controller: 'formController'
    })
    .state('form.wizard', {
        url:'/wizard',
        templateUrl: 'wizard/wizardSelection.html'
    })
    .state('form.submitorg', {
        url:'/submitPartner',
        templateUrl: 'wizard/submitOrgForm.html'
    })
    .state('form.agreements', {
        url:'/agreements',
        templateUrl: 'wizard/selectAgreement.html'
    })
... more routing goes here
```

My Controller logic goes here

```
controller('formController', function($scope, $state) {

$scope.getNextView = function(viewNumber){

    var viewState = 'form.error';

    if(viewNumber == 1){
       viewState = 'form.submitOrg'
    }
    else if(viewNumber == 2){
         viewState = 'form.agreements'
    }
    else if(viewNumber == 3){
         viewState = 'xxxx'
    }
    else if(viewNumber == 4){
         viewState = 'yyyyy'
    }
    else if(viewNumber == 5){

        if($scope.formData.Modeltype == 'C'){
              viewState = 'form.setupanother'
         }
        else{
              viewState = 'form.submitnew'
        }
    }

    $state.go(viewState, {});  
};
```

And in my html view i have a button and it binds with the controller call. here is how it has written

First View

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-click="getNextView(1)">
```

Second View

```
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-click="getNextView(2)">
```

I'm able to move from Wizard view (1) to submitOrg view (2). But when i click next button from the submitOrg View (2) it is going back to Wizard (1) again not to Agreements (3). I did put alert right before the $state.go to make sure the variable is updated with right view name, yes it is. Everything looks fine but it is not going to go to agreements view (3).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Primary Issue

Your `$state.go(viewState, {});`  is being overridden by your HTML's `href"#"`.

This would trigger your app's `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(viewState);`.

### Typo

Also, you need to capitalize the `o` in `.state('form.submitorg'` like this:

```
.state('form.submitOrg', {
  url: '/submitPartner',
  templateUrl: 'submitOrgForm.html'
})
```

You have two options:

## Option #1 - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WEiWjCYjur25hfvp9vMw?p=preview)

Just remove the `#` from `href="#"`.

(Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019284/ui-router-state-go-vs-ui-sref-is-making-me-nuts-in-angularjs))

## Option #2 - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/caWGZeStJMcCo2hSF9m1?p=preview)

Pass `$event` into your `ng-click` like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-click="getNextView(1, $event)">View #1</a>
```

Then in your controller's `$scope.getNextView` function add `$event.preventDefault();` like this:

```
$scope.getNextView = function(viewNumber, $event) {
    $event.preventDefault(); // prevents href from overriding $state.go
    var viewState = 'form.error';
    if (viewNumber == 1) {
        viewState = 'form.submitOrg'
    } else if (viewNumber == 2) {
        viewState = 'form.agreements'
    } else if (viewNumber == 3) {
        viewState = 'xxxx'
    } else if (viewNumber == 4) {
        viewState = 'yyyyy'
    } else if (viewNumber == 5) {
        if ($scope.formData.Modeltype == 'C') {
            viewState = 'form.setupanother'
        } else {
            viewState = 'form.submitnew'
        }
    }
    $state.go(viewState);
};
```

(Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186462/can-you-use-ng-click-with-ui-sref))